# Drawing in multiple UIViews causes lag. Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, core-graphics

I'm making a multiplayer game which involves drawing lines. I have 10 different custom UIViews where I draw an line using Core Graphics in an unique color. All views are stacked upon each other and are semi-transparent. The reason why I draw each color in corresponding UIView and not a single one is because I want to let the user be able to clear a specific view. However, If I draw in all of these views the same time, significant amount of lag will occur. If I check the time profiler most of the time is spent on drawing. But it's not that bad and should not cause that much lag. So, is there any way to let me draw in multiple UIViews (or something else), without causing this lag. Is it my code who causes this lag or is it the UIView?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
//create a image reference from the bitmap and then draw it in the context of the UIView. 

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGImageRef cacheImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(cacheContext);

  CGContextDrawImage(context, self.bounds, cacheImage);
   CGImageRelease(cacheImage);
}

-(void)draw{
 //drawing code. Could ignore the Beizer curve algorithm here.

 CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(cacheContext, [color CGColor]);
 CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(cacheContext, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);

 CGContextSetLineCap(cacheContext, kCGLineCapButt);
 CGContextSetLineWidth(cacheContext, 6+thickness);

        point0 = point1;
        point1 = point2; // previous previous point
        point2 = pos; // previous touch point
        point3 = currentpos;

        double x0 = (point0.x > -1) ? point0.x : point1.x; //after 4 touches we should have a back anchor point, if not, use the current anchor point
        double y0 = (point0.y > -1) ? point0.y : point1.y; //after 4 touches we should have a back anchor point, if not, use the current anchor point
        double x1 = point1.x;
        double  y1 =  point1.y;
        double x2 =  point2.x;
        double  y2 =  point2.y;
        double  x3 = point3.x;
        double  y3 = point3.y;



    // Assume we need to calculate the control
    // points between (x1,y1) and (x2,y2).
    // Then x0,y0 - the previous vertex,
    //      x3,y3 - the next one.

    double xc1 = (x0 + x1) / 2.0;
    double yc1 = (y0 + y1) / 2.0;
    double xc2 = (x1 + x2) / 2.0;
    double yc2 = (y1 + y2) / 2.0;
    double xc3 = (x2 + x3) / 2.0;
    double yc3 = (y2 + y3) / 2.0;

    double len1 = sqrt((x1-x0) * (x1-x0) + (y1-y0) * (y1-y0));
    double len2 = sqrt((x2-x1) * (x2-x1) + (y2-y1) * (y2-y1));
    double len3 = sqrt((x3-x2) * (x3-x2) + (y3-y2) * (y3-y2));

    double k1 = len1 / (len1 + len2);
    double k2 = len2 / (len2 + len3);

    double xm1 = xc1 + (xc2 - xc1) * k1;
    double ym1 = yc1 + (yc2 - yc1) * k1;

    double xm2 = xc2 + (xc3 - xc2) * k2;
    double ym2 = yc2 + (yc3 - yc2) * k2;
    double smooth_value = 0.8;
    // Resulting control points. Here smooth_value is mentioned
    // above coefficient K whose value should be in range [0...1].
    float ctrl1_x = xm1 + (xc2 - xm1) * smooth_value + x1 - xm1;
    float ctrl1_y = ym1 + (yc2 - ym1) * smooth_value + y1 - ym1;

    float ctrl2_x = xm2 + (xc2 - xm2) * smooth_value + x2 - xm2;
    float ctrl2_y = ym2 + (yc2 - ym2) * smooth_value + y2 - ym2;



        CGContextMoveToPoint(cacheContext, point1.x, point1.y);
        CGContextAddCurveToPoint(cacheContext, ctrl1_x, ctrl1_y, ctrl2_x, ctrl2_y, point2.x, point2.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(cacheContext);




    CGRect dirtyPoint1 = CGRectMake(point1.x-(8+thickness)/2, point1.y-(8+thickness)/2, (8+thickness), (8+thickness));
    CGRect dirtyPoint2 = CGRectMake(point2.x-(8+thickness)/2, point2.y-(8+thickness)/2, (8+thickness), (8+thickness));

    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:CGRectUnion(dirtyPoint1, dirtyPoint2)];
```

}

Comment: Is your drawing code intentionally outside of `drawRect:`? Try running the time profiler in Instruments against your app and see where it's spending the most time

Comment: I've already done that as I already wrote. But it looks like whats causing the lag is stacking UIView on top of each other and drawing simultaneously.

Comment: Have you tried just one `UIView` with multiple `CALyers`?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's lagging, but you are creating a lot of extra buffers here. Why are you using the extra bitmap context in each view? Did you try it without that - just drawing the curve in drawRect? Also, drawing 10 curves in one view's drawRect should not be that bad, you might be condense it all to one view, and 'clear' one line by simply redrawing them all and skipping the cleared one.